# Facebook android sdk login failed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have implemented the **FB login button** on a **Fragment** with the latest android SDK (3.15.0).

Everything works fine for android >= 4 but it doesn't work for older versions :

After the login button is being pressed, it turns systematically to a *CLOSES_LOGIN_FAILED* state without getting the facebook dialog box.

The code looks like this :

```
Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(callback);
List<String> readPermissions = Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email", "user_photos");
openRequest.setPermissions(readPermissions);
session.openForRead(openRequest);
```

And the callback function like this :

```
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state,
    final Exception exception) {    
           onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};
```

Obvioulsy followed by :

```
private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session,
    SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state == SessionState.OPENED)
        {
            requestFbUserInfos(session);
        }
        else if (state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED) {
                       //
        }
        else if (state == SessionState.CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED) {
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        }
        else if (state == SessionState.CLOSED) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried logging the exception and seeing what the error is? Also, you don't need to call session.close... if the state is already in CLOSED or CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED.

Comment: Yes, there is no special error attached. Thanks for the sesson close advice.

Comment: Automagically it works now ...